# Entity Framework OrDefault value types

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

I have a LINQ query with a Where clause that could return either a single entity, or none. I am only interested in a single property so I would use **Select** followed by **SingleOrDefault(Async)**.

However, the property I am interested in is a value type. Is it possible to execute the query in such a way that I can get a nullable type, rather than a default value, when the query returns no results?

I can of course query the entire object and simply only return that one property, but I wonder if there's a better way of doing it.

Comment: Please give an example showing the class properties and what properties you are trying to select into nullable values.

Comment: Why don't you just use FirstOrDefault(x=> x.Condition) instead of Where, Select and SingleOrDefault ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Select` to cast your value type to a nullable type so it will be null instead of default value.

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int>();

// this will be null
var number1 = numbers.Select(x => (int?)x).SingleOrDefault();

// this will be default value which is zero
var number2 = numbers.SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: Works perfectly; I didn't know Select worked like that.